# Choice of GraphLayout to draw undirected graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to adjust the GraphLayout of the undirected graph given in the code below, which looks like the following figure:

[image]

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}} // 
  Map[Apply[UndirectedEdge]], VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4}, 
 GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
 VertexStyle -> {LightGray}, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[15, Black, Bold, Italic]]
```

Please any help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding"`?

Comment: @kglr No, it doesn't give me the required graph. Instead, "HighDimensionalEmbedding" works, but the position of the vertices are not balanced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** Use `{"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> - 45 Degree}` as the setting for `GraphLayout`:

```
Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4},
 {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}} // Map[Apply[UndirectedEdge]], 
 GraphLayout -> {"CircularEmbedding", "Offset" -> - 45 Degree}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
 VertexSize -> Medium, 
 VertexStyle -> {LightGray}, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[15, Black, Bold, Italic]]
```

[image]

**2.** Use `{4,1,3,2}` as the vertex list in the first argument of `Graph`  and set `GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding"`:

```
Graph[{4, 1, 3, 2},
 {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}} // Map[Apply[UndirectedEdge]], 
 GraphLayout -> "GridEmbedding", 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
 VertexStyle -> {LightGray}, 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[15, Black, Bold, Italic]]
```

[image]